# Using Variables in MySql

Tags: mysql

I Have the following function used to increment groups of values:

```
SET @IncrementValue := 0;
SET @VIN := 0;

UPDATE tbInventoryMedia
SET 
  @IncrementValue := IF(@VIN <> strVIN, @IncrementValue + 1, 1),
  @VIN := strVIN, 
  tbInventoryMedia.intOrder = @IncrementValue;
```

This looks like a pretty straight forward query... increments if the last vin was different and restarts the numbering.  Any ideas why it is showing a compile error after SET?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No idea, unless you post the error message.

Comment: Generic error message is generic: "Error next to @incrementValue"... I gave you all I know sadly :(

Comment: what tool are you using to run the query?

Comment: Placed in a stored procedure via navicat.

Comment: *"Error next to @incrementValue"*, note that the case doesn't match your example. Is this a typo?

Comment: @DaveC: is the error thrown when you create the stored proc or when you run it? Please post the script for the stored proc.

Comment: Yup, typo... the location of the error is directly after SET as said in the OP

Comment: Upon creation of the SP... however, running it in command line also gives the same error.  I think it checks the queries before creating an SP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot update session variables with `SET` which is a part of `UPDATE`.

Try this:

```
SET @IncrementValue := 0;
SET @VIN := 0;

UPDATE  tbInventoryMedia
SET     tbInventoryMedia.intOrder = CASE @vin WHEN @vin := strVin THEN @IncrementValue := @IncrementValue + 1 ELSE @IncrementValue := 1 END
ORDER BY
        strVIN;
```